# How does the e2e architecture concept look for GitOps / Gitlab-IaC-k8s-Webapp?

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci, gitops

I'm lost in the forest of GitOps / DevOps with k8s deployment

I find information on

- Infrastructure as Code (Terraform)
- Kubernetes k8s cluster, all the k8s manifest, Docker Container
- Flux

but it's not clear how these tie together.

Is there recommended reading on the big picture?
I wasn't successful in finding a `hello world e2e pipeline` which shows the deployment `Gitlab-IaC-(AWS/GCP/...)-k8s-WebApp`, probably you know something?

Comment: any update on this ? feel free to update the status of question if below answer resolves your issue.

Comment: This is a broad question topic, with several answers that depend on your experiences. Can you probably narrow the question down? Or feel free to pung me via PM to help you to sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to my [Github](https://github.com/harsh4870/basic-gitops-terraform-gcp-instance) which has very normal basic GitOps terraform to provision the **GCP** **instance**.

It could be different as you can have **multiple repos** storing the configs of **Gitlab** **CI** and you can important it another **repo** like modules.

Generally, **Infra**(Terraform) and **App**(Helm, K8s YAML) deployment will be in different **repositories** so both have **separate** **Gitlab** **CI** config and **workflow**.

[This](https://github.com/harsh4870/basic-ci-cd-cloudbuild) is not the **Gitops** example but it's **CI/CD** with **GCP cloudbuild** will give you idea you can write the **gitlab-ci.yml**

**[Server.js](https://github.com/harsh4870/basic-ci-cd-cloudbuild/blob/main/server.js)** is normally code get **docker build** when commit occur to Gitrepo and there is another trigger config file when you run that it updates **[deployment.yaml](https://github.com/harsh4870/basic-ci-cd-cloudbuild/blob/main/cloudbuild-deployment.yaml)** file with sed command set the **Image** and **apply** the config file.

Comment: the examples look reasonable but very hard to get a quick understanding. If you probably could add more insights to its readme, that would help.